# Databricks getArgument value cannot be used within Spark SQL IN clause

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am getting a list of comma separated strings from a databricks notebook widget but I cannot use that value within Spark SQL's IN clause

I am within a %sql cell within the notebook and would like to NOT have to jump into %py or %scala cell type.

Also, I cannot use a select statement within the IN clause as the IN clause is NOT within a select filter. One gets an error: "IN/EXISTS predicate sub-queries can only be used in a Filter" if you try that syntax.

Here ITEM is a widget created like this in a %sql cell

CREATE WIDGET TEXT ITEM DEFAULT "'0111','0112'"

```
select *
from items_table
where ItemSKU in (string(getArgument("ITEM")));
```

or

```
select *
from items_table
where ItemSKU in (getArgument("ITEM"));
```

it does not return any rows

But if I directly substitute the value of the comma separated string in code, i.e.

```
select *
from items_table
where ItemSKU in ('0111','0112');
```

I get the expected result.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible, try:

```
...
WHERE ItemSKU IN (SELECT explode(split(getArgument("ITEM"),',')))
```

This will also work for multi-select widgets.

The text widget option will be susceptible to user error if your users are allowed to enter text directly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have multiple items as a default value of a `multiselect` widget, and definetely not a `text` widget.

If you look at the signature of the `multiselect` function

```
multiselect(name: String, defaultValue: String, choices: Seq, label: String)
```

You can see that the `defaultValue` only accepts a String while the `choices` is a `Sequence`.  I know this is the scala function and you are lookign for the SQL version, but this implies that there is not meant to be a `multiselect` default option yet that actually has multiple selections.

Link - https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/dev-tools/dbutils.html

Comment: hi @big_mike_boiii, the widget is not a multi-select widget its just a text widget. I want to send a string with multiple values - which are valid within the SQL IN clause e.g. '0111','0112' - and I should be able to send those values via a text widget. I am not sure why the SQL IN clause does not with getArgument